# basehttpserver does not respond to other requests

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I open my local server on Android (192.168.1.4) and on pc at the same time, pc never shows page (it is loading and loading and loading...) - this error raises when I kill my server:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.1.4', 54734)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 655, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 340, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 310, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

my server script:

```
# !/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

PORT = 20000


class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def log_message(self, format, *args):
        return

    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        self._set_headers()
        if self.path == "/other":
            self.wfile.write("other")

        if self.path == "/something":
            self.wfile.write('something')

    def do_HEAD(self):
        self._set_headers()

    def do_POST(self):
        self._set_headers()
        self.wfile.write("hello post")


def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=S, port=PORT):
    server_address = ('', port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    httpd.serve_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from sys import argv

    if len(argv) == 2:
        run(port=int(argv[1]))
    else:
        run()
```

What is wrong with my code please?

Comment: Have you opend the port 20000 in Windows firewall? Why don't you try a more classic port number like 80 or 8080?

Comment: yes, this script runs on linux machine, all ports are open.

Answer (score 0):

I think your server works well: like any server, it runs indefinitely.

To see it working, just point your browser on the following URL: http://localhost:20000/something or http://127.0.0.1:20000/something.

You should get the text "something".

You should consider using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

Comment: yes, when I open http://server_ip_in_lan:20000/something from pc, it works  ok. Then I open it from Android device, it shows page ok. Then I try to open the same website from pc again, and now it just loading and loading and loading... so I must kill server and then it raises that error.

Answer (score 0):

No idea, if this is correct approach but setting timeout helped:

```
...
        def log_message(self, format, *args):
            return
        def setup(self):
            BaseHTTPRequestHandler.setup(self)
            self.request.settimeout(0.5)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

https://pymotw.com/2/BaseHTTPServer/#threading-and-forking says:

> HTTPServer is a simple subclass of SocketServer.TCPServer, and does not use multiple threads or processes to handle requests. To add threading or forking, create a new class using the appropriate mix-in from SocketServer.